# Ajax 'CalendarExtender' displays in dd/mm/yy frontend and save in the database in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: asp.net, ajax, date, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an Ajax CalendarExtender. In this I want to show data in the `dd/mm/yy` format frontend to users, but I want to save the data in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

```
<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="calFromDate" PopupButtonID="imgCalFromDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFromDate" Format="dd/MM/yy">
  </ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

ASP.NET C# backend code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FRMDT", DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text.Trim(), "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

I get the following error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

when the textbox values are for example:

12/11/09 
12/11/17

Answer (score 0):

Use the following. It always work.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FRMDT", Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text.Trim()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Comment: getting Error  Too many arguments to 'Public Function AddWithValue(parameterName As String, value As Object) As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter'. \

Comment: try passing a null in the parameters. this error is not related with date parameter

Comment: But it's not a run time error.it's Compile time error

Comment: pls tell how to do it

Comment: try removing your last argument or send me the sanp of it.may be i can help more.